# Python. Как из списка словарей сделать словарь, где значение каждого ключа - список со словарями

Tags: python, список, словарь

Имеется список словарей:

```
[{'Категория': 'Белые вина', 'Название': 'Белая леди', 'Сорт': 'Дамский пальчик', 'Цена': 399, 'Картинка': 'belaya_ledi.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Напитки', 'Название': 'Коньяк классический', 'Сорт': '', 'Цена': 350, 'Картинка': 'konyak_klassicheskyi.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Белые вина', 'Название': 'Ркацители', 'Сорт': 'Ркацители', 'Цена': 499, 'Картинка': 'rkaciteli.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Красные вина', 'Название': 'Черный лекарь', 'Сорт': 'Качич', 'Цена': 399, 'Картинка': 'chernyi_lekar.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Красные вина', 'Название': 'Хванчкара', 'Сорт': 'Александраули', 'Цена': 550, 'Картинка': 'hvanchkara.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Белые вина', 'Название': 'Кокур', 'Сорт': 'Кокур', 'Цена': 450, 'Картинка': 'kokur.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Красные вина', 'Название': 'Киндзмараули', 'Сорт': 'Саперави', 'Цена': 550, 'Картинка': 'kindzmarauli.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Напитки', 'Название': 'Чача', 'Сорт': '', 'Цена': 299, 'Картинка': 'chacha.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Напитки', 'Название': 'Коньяк кизиловый', 'Сорт': '', 'Цена': 350, 'Картинка': 'konyak_kizilovyi.png'}]
```

Из него нужно сделать словарь, ключи которого - категории вин, значения - списки словарей с винами.
Как сделать знаю, НО по условию в коде вообще не должно быть названий категорий для того, чтобы если в коде появится новая категория, не пришлось бы лезть в код и дописывать. Пример решения на фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я делал :

```
white_wines = [wine for wine in wines_2 if wine.get('Категория') == 'Белые вина']
red_wines = [wine for wine in wines_2 if wine.get('Категория') == 'Красные вина']
drinks = [wine for wine in wines_2 if wine.get('Категория') == 'Напитки']
categories = [white_wines, red_wines, drinks]
categories_names = ['Белые вина', 'Красные вина', 'Напитки']
wines_by_category = dict(zip(categories_names, categories))
```

Но тут указаны категории вин копипастой, что нарушает условия задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто соберите словарь в цикле

```
l = [{'Категория': 'Белые вина', 'Название': 'Белая леди', 'Сорт': 'Дамский пальчик', 'Цена': 399, 'Картинка': 'belaya_ledi.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Напитки', 'Название': 'Коньяк классический', 'Сорт': '', 'Цена': 350, 'Картинка': 'konyak_klassicheskyi.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Белые вина', 'Название': 'Ркацители', 'Сорт': 'Ркацители', 'Цена': 499, 'Картинка': 'rkaciteli.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Красные вина', 'Название': 'Черный лекарь', 'Сорт': 'Качич', 'Цена': 399, 'Картинка': 'chernyi_lekar.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Красные вина', 'Название': 'Хванчкара', 'Сорт': 'Александраули', 'Цена': 550, 'Картинка': 'hvanchkara.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Белые вина', 'Название': 'Кокур', 'Сорт': 'Кокур', 'Цена': 450, 'Картинка': 'kokur.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Красные вина', 'Название': 'Киндзмараули', 'Сорт': 'Саперави', 'Цена': 550, 'Картинка': 'kindzmarauli.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Напитки', 'Название': 'Чача', 'Сорт': '', 'Цена': 299, 'Картинка': 'chacha.png'},
 {'Категория': 'Напитки', 'Название': 'Коньяк кизиловый', 'Сорт': '', 'Цена': 350, 'Картинка': 'konyak_kizilovyi.png'}]

res = {}

for x in l:
    res.setdefault(x['Категория'], []).append(x)

print(res)
```